# Web Crawling with SpiderCrawl from scrapy Returning 302

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl this website : https://hypeauditor.com/top-youtube-video-games/

using Scrapy, at the first page it runs good, Scrapy returns Scraped (200.. With the Data

but the next page scrapy doesn't return scraped (200) but crawled (302) it doesn't return any data

This is my Crawler code :

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class chnlids(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "chnlids"
    
    allowed_domains = ["hypeauditor.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://hypeauditor.com/top-youtube-video-games/"]
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'dont_redirect':True})
    

    def parse(self,response):
      i = 0
      for key in response.css("div.contributor__content a.contributor::attr(href)").getall():

        yield{
            "channel_id" : response.css("div.contributor__content a.contributor::attr(href)")[i].get()
        }
        i += 1
        
      if(self.page_number != 10):
        self.page_number += 1
        next_page = f'https://hypeauditor.com/top-youtube-video-games/?p={self.page_number}'
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse,meta={'dont_redirect': True}
```

The result is the same as I described before:

```py
....
2023-04-30 10:32:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://hypeauditor.com/top-youtube-video-games/>
{'channel_id': '/youtube/UCwIWAbIeu0xI0ReKWOcw3eg/'}
2023-04-30 10:32:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (302) <GET https://hypeauditor.com/top-youtube-video-games/?p=2> (referer: https://hypeauditor.com/top-youtube-video-games/)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py:83: UserWarning: Selector got both text and root, root is being ignored.
.....
```

I have tried several things like :

**- `handle_httpsstatus_list = [302]`**

`meta={'dont_redirect': True}` in Request.meta**

**- Added `REDIRECT_ENABLED = False` in settings.py**

but all that did not work, i expected the crawled 302 returning data like scraped 200

I don't understand where my error, whether it's in the redirect when switching pages or which part I don't know

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: It wants you to sign in, so it redirects you to the sign in page.

Comment: @SuperUser so. does my scrapy have to login to the website ?, do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you have to log in. [Read this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=login#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login).